# http request every 500ms until request complete Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, settimeout

I am seeking to request the server with constant requests every 500ms. 
I want to request at first and IF the request is not complete after 500ms , I want to make the same request again. Then wait again 500ms and check if it is incomplete. I want to repeat this process until the request is complete.

Right now, my request looks like this:

```
$http({
      method: method,
      url:baseUrl,
      headers: {
       'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       'Data-Type': 'json'
       },
       data: resultService.sendData(true),
      cache:false
    })
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){  // accepts more parameters
      $timeout(function(){
        resultService.activeSearch=false;
        $timeout(function(){
          request= $filter('orderBy')(data,['price','id']);
        },0);
      },1000);

    })
    .error(function(){ 
      resultService.activeSearch=false;
      function(){
        request={error:1};
      };
    });

  };
```

I thought about using something like this

```
(function tick(){
  $http({
    method: method,
    url:baseUrl,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Data-Type': 'json'
    },
    data: resultService.sendData(true),
    cache:false
  })
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){  // accepts more parameters
      request=data;
      $timeout(tick,500);
      $timeout(
        function(){resultService.activeSearch=false;
      },1000);

    })
     .error(function(){ 
         $timeout(tick,500);
          resultService.activeSearch=false;
          function(){
            request={error:1};
          };
        });
})();
```

This does not work as intended. Where am I wrong?

Comment: what is the behaviour of this code?

Comment: It seems that a new request is not made at all after 500ms. Is it, because I do not obtain an error after 500ms and therefore no new request is made? It seems to me, that I have to start the tick function somewhere else before getting into .success?

Comment: there is also a  $interval  service  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 1):

Use the timeout argument of $http

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, $http){
  $scope.logs=''
  
  // Will try to get targetUrl every 500ms, then call successCallback with the data
  function tryToGet(targetUrl,successCallback){
    $scope.logs+='\n New attempt \n';
    
    // Try a get with the timeout argument
    var attempt = $http.get(targetUrl,{timeout:500})
    
    // On error, try again
    attempt.error(function(){
      tryToGet(targetUrl,successCallback);
    });
    
    // On success, exectute the callback
    attempt.success(successCallback);
  }
  function whenOk(data){
    $scope.logs+=data
  }
  tryToGet('http://google.com', whenOk)
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <pre ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-bind="logs">
  
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good. I will set up the backend now and will see if it performs as I hope. But the tests work well..

Comment: The google page doesnt timeout, i didnt find a page that would just not answer. If the page is down (404 error), it will chain requests at top speed, so maybe a timeout before the retry should be added. Does it have to be exactly 500ms or can it be 1000ms for timeout errors and 500ms for other errors ?